# react-router Location did not match any routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

There is a login component. My application entry point is login page. After successful login, moved to main page(dashboard & navigation). After successful login main page is displaying with nav component and dashboard.But navigations are not working. I am getting error:

react-router Location "/examples" did not match any routes 
react-router Location "/dashboard" did not match any routes

My login Component is

```
var React = require('react');
var {Link} = require('react-router');
var Dashboard = require('Dashboard');

var Login = React.createClass ({
onFormSubmit: function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = '/main'
},
render: function(){
return (
<div>
 <h1 className="text-center">Login</h1>
  <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
    <input type="text" ref="username"/>

    <button className="button">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>
 )
 } 
 });

 module.exports = Login;
```

My Dashboard component is

```
 var React = require('react');
 var Nav = require('Nav');

 var Dashboard = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
       <h1> Dashboard</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
 }

 module.exports = Dashboard;
```

Main component Main.jsx

```
var React = require('react');
var Nav = require('Nav');

 var Main = (props) => {
   return (
     <div>
        <h1> Main</h1>
     <Nav/>
     <div className="row">
     <div className="columns medium-6 large-4 small-centered">
       {props.children}
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   );
  }

  module.exports = Main;
```

Main app.jsx file is

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var {Route, Router, IndexRoute, browserHistory} = require('react-   router');
var Login = require('Login');
var Dashboard = require('Dashboard');
var About = require('About');
var Examples = require('Examples');
var Main = require('Main');


require('style!css!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.css')
$(document).foundation();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Login}/>
    <Route path="/main" component={Main}>
       <Route path="about" component={About}/>
       <Route path="examples" component={Examples}/>
       <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

My server.js file:

```
 var express = require('express');

 // Create our app
 var app = express();

 app.get(['/', '/main'], function(req, res){
 res.sendfile('./public/index.html')
});


app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Express server is up on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared your application routes like so:

```
<Route path="/main" component={Main}>
   <Route path="about" component={About}/>
   <Route path="examples" component={Examples}/>
   <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}/>
</Route>
```

So you should be using:

```
/main/examples
/main/dashboard
```

instead of:

```
/examples
/dashboard
```

Comment: I tried /main/examples, 
  /main/dashboard. Still not working

Comment: What If my root path has a uri param like "/main/:some_id"?

Comment: We are facing the same problem, just adding /main/ eqv. does not help. Anyone solved this?

Comment: Ok, we found out our problem - that the application menu was actually still refering to the old paths.
/main/:some_id is still a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you are routing to `/main` on login which is why your `Dashboard` and `Main` page is working. If you want to view the `examples` page you need to redirect to `/main/examples` and if `about` then `/main/about`. Also you should always redirect using the `react-router` API. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router#answer-34863577) answer to figure out how to redirect programmatically using react-router

Answer (score 0):

React Router v4 with webpack Implementation as below

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <h1>main page</h1>} />
      <Route path="/about" render={() => <h1>about page</h1>} />
      <Route path="/contact" render={() => <h1>contact page</h1>} />
    </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
  
  //webpack  build  script change add --history-api-fallback in package.json file
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback"
    }
    
   Now run following command on terminal: npm start
```